# HTTP Request Memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using this code, but when profiling, it tells me I have a many memory leaks within `response_error`, `request` and `_response` variables.

I tried several places to put a `release` code of each variable used in function, but it keeps crashing with and without error message too. (most often it is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` which points to memory access error)

I think it could be problem of `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` method, but I'm not sure.

Can somebody please give me an advice or place `release` blocks in right place of this code?

Thanks

```
NSString *request_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/api/arg1/%@/arg2/%@/arg3/%@",self._api_key,self._device_id,self._token];
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:request_url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:requestURL];
NSError *response_error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *_response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&_response error:&response_error];
NSString *str_response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return [[str_response JSONValue] valueForKey:@"pairing"];
```

where variables are defined like

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  NSString *_device_id;
  NSString *_token;
  NSString *_api_key;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_device_id;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_api_key;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_token;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaking `_respone` and `response_error` by needlessly allocating them. You are passing a pointer to your pointer to a method that will just change the pointer creating a leak. Also you need to autorelease `str_response`

```
NSError *response_error = nil; //Do not alloc/init
NSHTTPURLResponse *_response = nil; //Do not alloc/init
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&_response error:&response_error];
NSString *str_response = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
return [[str_response JSONValue] valueForKey:@"pairing"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling alloc/init and then not calling release or autorelease, odds are you are going to leak memory.

Comment: but question is where and how place those release blocks, because `NSAutorelease` block with `drain` right before return was not handling leaks correctly, and my hand written releases caused memory access error.